# how to get result with cursor and paging using ZSCAN command with stackexchange.redis library?

Tags: c#, redis, paging, stackexchange.redis

I am using `stackexchange.redis`. 
in that `zscan` is giving all matched value
**I  want to get exactly given page size result and next cursor for remaining values.**

> I have debugged its source code library in that i found that they are
>   scanning entire source value until cursor became zero and provides all
>   matched values.
>
> so could we can get result as per cursor same as redis command Zscan.

**here is my code snap**

```
 using (ConnectionMultiplexer conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(conf))
 {
           var dbs = conn.GetDatabase();                         
           int currentpage = 0,pagesize=20;
           var scanresult = dbs.SortedSetScan("key", "an*", pagesize, 0, 0, CommandFlags.None);
 }
```

here I am getting all values of matching criteria instead of page size and next cursor.

so help out if any one has done it before

Comment: Why not use ZRANGEBYLEX? The result will be the same and you have more control over it.

Comment: we don't want  to play with score we need to perform pure "zscan"    with cursor

Comment: if you want play with cursor you can get it by


 `var cursor = (IScanningCursor) scanresult;`

Comment: This was because of their internal code structure so its now working with other library.

Comment: that worked for me too. thanks

Comment: ohh yes only  this  was solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of stack stackexchange.redis library code. its scanning as per enumerable method. so its not working same as redis command line.

To solve this issue we have used another  redis client library called **csredis**

```
using (var redis = new RedisClient("yourhost"))
{
    string ping = redis.Ping();
     var scanresult=redis.ZScan(key, cursor, pattern, pagesize);

}
```

As shown in above code we will get all dadta into "scanresult".